# What does `struct A_API B{}` mean?

Tags: c++

I'm reading `pytorch`'s C++ source code, and I notice that it declears struct or class like this:

```
struct CAFFE2_API SparseTensorImpl : public TensorImpl {
...
};
```

The code is in `pytorch/aten/src/ATen/SparseTensorImpl.h`

In fact , I've never seen such code before. What I've seen were all `struct A` or `class A`. Although it may not matter, I'm still confusing what `CAFFE2_API` means here.

Comment: `CAFFE2_API` must be a macro defined in some other header file. This is typically used to introduce some compiler and/or operating system dependent meta-features to the class in question (such a exportable from a shared library, not exportable, etc...) To figure out what it does you must figure out where it is defined, what it is, then check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: You can go to definition and see how it is defined, it's probably a precompiler directive holding some conventions like __cdecl or similiar.

Comment: [pytorch Export.h](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/c10/macros/Export.h#L97)